# Unable to save Policy in Azure APIM

Tags: azure, azure-api-management

I have been able to work in Azure APIM with no problems until yesterday. Another member on my team can edit and save with no problems; but my save to an Inbound Processing rule always fails with:

> Could not save policy for "Access API 1.2" API. Please try again
>   later.

Thoughts?

Of Note:

- Our companies security access team verifies that I am a `contributor` to APIM
- I login in through the companies' two factor authentication system into Azure.
- Same results on Edge/Chrome.
- I can update individual endpoint api policies.

---

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Our company opened a Microsoft Support ticket on this and their response was

> You are running into a known issue with APIM integration with ARM. The
>   dev team is working on a fix for this issue now and we are told it
>   will get deployed by this evening.

The following day it was working for me

> The APIM dev team fixed the issue late yesterday and you should now
>   see the ability to update policies for the API scope too.

---

Note to anyone running into this situation in the future the secondary advice given revolved around the browser which  was

> Make sure you’ll not pulling down cached files. Try loading an
>   in-private session or press CTRL+F5 to refresh the page and pull down
>   new files.